# Is it possible to know when an HTTP response arrived to the client, in the server? (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, networking

Quick question (yes I've googled it first, no success): I have an ASP.NET simple web handler (those .ashx files) and while I can use context.Response.Write() and such, I don't seem to find a way to detect when the response -actually- arrived to the client.

Is it possible? Something homogeneous to the TCP protocol where you can know the package was successfully sent.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because confirmation of arrival is

1. always delayed
2. never reliable (see the [Generals Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals'_Problem))

Because of (2) it is impossible to reliably determine that data has arrived in all cases assuming a potentially lossy network.

You can probably devise something that is good enough. Make the client issue a second HTTP call to let the server know that the first call's result arrived.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think HTTP handles the confirmation of message exposed in the request/response, and I'm pretty sure there is no "out of the box" support for this within the built in request/response objects in page or controller classes.

What you may want to look at, is a web sockets library like SignalR or SocketIO, both of which allow for a more bidirectional communication that sounds more like what you are looking for.